# Proving supremum of set of all different "net area of finite number of circles inside a square of side $a=a^2$

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, circles, area, supremum-and-infimum

Take a square of side $a$.

Now take finite number of circles $(C^1_1,C^1_2,C^1_3,...,C^1_{n_1 \in \mathbb{N}})$ inside the square such that all of their intersection is empty set. Find its net area and call it $ar(C^1)$.

Now take another finite number of circles $(C^2_1,C^2_2,C^2_3,...,C^2_{n_2 \in \mathbb{N}})$ inside the square such that all of their intersection is empty set. Find its net area and call it $ar(C^2)$.

Keep on doing this and find net area of each possible "collection of finite number of circles inside the square". Then make a set $\gamma=\{ ar(C^1),ar(C^2),ar(C^3),... \}$

Finally what I need to show is:

$$\sup \gamma=a^2 \tag1$$

> **My heuristic guess:**
>
> To prove this, I need to prove the following:
>
> > by adding more and more circles inside the square, we can make the net area of all circles as close as we want to $a^2$
>
> This seems true but can anyone give a hint of how to prove the above statement so that I can prove $(1)$?

---